# How to change TR style on TD Click in React Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React table and want to change Tr style on one column click.

I am not able to find any documentation or sample to achive this simple task.

```
  header: 'Name',
  columns: [{
    render: (rowInfo, column) => {
            const onClicked = () => {
                console.log('How i can change Tr style here');
            };
            return (
                <span onClick= {onClicked} className='number'>close</span>
            )
        }
  }
```

Refer code pen link 
http://codepen.io/parmodkrarora/pen/wdWoBd/?editors=0010

Comment: That component needs to have "STATE". And in that state - you need a prop named something like TOGGLE: false. Then onClick - you tell toggle = !toggle and then setState with the new value. That will tell toggle to always switch whatever its current value is. Then on the HTML element you set the className to have an if statement to switch the css class:
<span onClick= {onClicked} className="number {this.props.toggle === false ? 'clicked' : 'unclicked' }">close</span>

Then you can style that css class however you want.

Comment: In coulmn render callback, i am able to access rowInfo object, but i on changing rowInfo object TRComponent is not re-rendered.

Comment: Have a look on updated http://codepen.io/parmodkrarora/pen/wdWoBd/?editors=0011

Comment: Oh I see - ok then - what you need to do is still have a toggle on the column component, but it needs to pass props down to the child TR component so it knows if the column is clicked - and when to refresh. When you use the function setState - react will refresh.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion it works.

Comment: I put all the data in state and changed the state on click with flag selected. After changing state in click handler child component refresh automatically. Thanks Spencer BIgum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put all the data in state and changed the state on click with flag selected. After changing state in click handler child component refresh automatically. Thanks Spencer BIgum